# How do add a resource policy for sns to a sqs with serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, serverless-framework, amazon-sns

I have problems assigning my sqs queue the correct policy so that any sns topic can send a message to it whenever this queue gets subscribed to it. I tried to use `UpdatePolicy` and `Metadata` in serverless without any effect:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    DevNull:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        QueueName: ${self:custom.serviceName}-${self:provider.stage}-dev-null-queue
      UpdatePolicy:
        policy:
          statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service: sns.amazonaws.com
                Action: sqs:SendMessage
              Resource: '*'

      Metadata:
        AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource:
          policyStatements:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service: sns.amazonaws.com
              Action:
                - 'sqs:SendMessage'
              Resource: '*'
```

I also can not see any changes in the "Access policy(Permission)" tab in the aws console after deployment.
I subscribed an email address to double check if the messages are sent and I get them all via email but there is none in the sqs.

I found a [SAM template](https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-patterns/blob/main/sns-sqs/template.yaml) which does what I need but I have no idea how to write this with the serverless framework and I can not find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a QueuePolicy that will allows SNS to send a message to the queue. This is an example from one of my projects, hope it helps :)

```
Resources:
  MyQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties: 
      RedrivePolicy: 
        deadLetterTargetArn: 
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - MyQueueDLQ
            - Arn
        maxReceiveCount: 5

  MyQueueDLQ:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue

  SNSTopicToMyQueuePolicy:
      Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
      Properties:
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Sid: 'allow-sns-messages'
              Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service: 'sns.amazonaws.com'
              Resource:
                Fn::GetAtt:
                - MyQueue
                - Arn
              Action: 'SQS:SendMessage'
              # COMMENT THIS IN IF YOU WANT IT TO ONLY ALLOW A CERTAIN SNS TOPIC
              # Condition:
                # ArnEquals:
                  # 'aws:SourceArn':
                    # Ref: MySNSTopic
        Queues:
          - Ref: MyQueue

  // If you want the queue to subscribe to a certain topic
  QueueSubscription:
      Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
      Properties:
        TopicArn:
          Ref: MySNSTopic
        Endpoint:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - MyQueue
            - Arn
        Protocol: sqs
        RawMessageDelivery: true
```